# Running a Shell script from php

Tags: php, linux, apache, shell, docker

I have a question that have been asked many time over the web, but none of the solutions help my case.

I need a very simple website with a single button, by which on click, a single shell command is executed to deploy a docker container.

For this I have 3 files all located in /var/www/html/:

1- Depl-Script (a simple Linux file, made executable by chmod +x and chmod 777, and does not have .sh extension, including a single command:

```
docker run -it -p 8080:8080 surrogate
```

2- a DepGUI.php

```
<?php
// $output=shell-exec("/var/www/html/Depl-Script"); //didn't work
$output=shell_exec("./Depl-Script"); //this doesn't work neither
echo $output; //prints 0
$output1=shell_exec("whoami"); //prints www-data
echo $output1;
?>
```

3- a Main.html, including:

```
<form action="DepGUI.php">
    <input type="submit" value="Open Script">
</form>
```

Shell-exec doesn't work for running the shell script. 
How do I know it doesn't work? I check docker containers, nothing is created.

What solutions I have tried:

1) The shell script (Dep-Script) works fine when I run it from CLI, by root user.

2)Just to make sure, I changed the etc/passwd file, found the line with www-data user and changed it's login shell to /bin/bash, and then by www-data (apache) user, I executed the same shell script, and it works. (I returned the /etc/passwd file to the original shape)

3)I have checked the /etc/php5/apache2/php.ini and /etc/php5/cli/php.ini and the exec, and shell_exec is not disabled.

4) I have checked the shell-exec and exec command with "sh" parameter, it did not work.

Any help/comment is appreciated in advance.
Thanks

Update:

I redirected errors to the output,

```
$output=shell_exec("./Depl-Script 2>&1");
```

I noticed the error is related to docker, "The input device is not a TTY" , then I got rid of -t in the docker command in the script (Dep-Script) and the error disappeared. I got a new error related to docker permissions and solved it using following link:

https://techoverflow.net/2017/03/01/solving-docker-permission-denied-while-trying-to-connect-to-the-docker-daemon-socket/

Comment: `shell-exec` is not a function. Do you mean [`shell_exec`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.shell-exec.php)?

Comment: Did you put the shebang on your one line script? maybe should be 2 lines script including it `#!/bin/bash`

Comment: If you can execute script with your account and cannot as web server, I recommend you to:
[1] redirect STDERR: 2>&1
[2] check if www-data is allowed to execute command (is in docker group)

Comment: @ tadman, thank you that was a typo error.

Comment: @ Pavel Tvaladze, Thank you so much, your hint saved me. I used your number [1] hint to find what the error is. First it was related to make it non interactive, then I got the second error which was related to your [2] hint,  docker permissions to current user.

Comment: @ OscarAkaElvis, yes Thanks.